# How Do I Fetch Article that has #exam and NOT #example in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to fetch Articles have `"#exam"` but I also get the ones that have `"#example"`

`content = "#exam tomorrow. I am prepared"`

`content1 = "#example one of ten"`

`hashtags = Article.objects.filter(content__contains = '#exam')`

Return both `content` and `content1` and I want just the Articles that contains `#exam`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly (but simple) hack would be to look for '#exam ' (note the whitespace) instead. Of course, this instantly breaks as soon as there's some other character there instead.

A more elegant solution would be to craft a `regex` query that would match against `#exam` but not `#example`. However, see the regex field lookup entry in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#regex) first, because the exact expression to pass will vary.